# Showing that the solution $x(t)$ never vanishes at any point $t$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following $x(t)$ integral solution defined for $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$:

$$
x(t) = \eta + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\beta \sin x(s) }{3 + e^{x(s)} + \cos x(s)} ds 
$$

where $\eta$ and $\beta$ are constants.

The question is asking to show that $\forall t_{1} \neq t_{2}$, $x(t_1) x(t_2) > 0, \eta \neq 0$.

Given that: I can show this $x(t)$ is a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$.

A formal solution to this problem I have is that:

Since $f(0)= 0$, it follows that $x(t)\equiv 0$ is an equilibrium point.Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $\exists t_1\neq t_2,\; x(t_1)x(t_2)\le 0$. Then $\exists t^*, x(t^*)=0$, which implies by uniqueness that $x(t)\equiv 0$. This contradicts $x(0)=\eta \neq 0$. Thus we must have $x(t_1)x(t_2)>0$.

In this case, $f(x(s)) = \frac{\beta \sin x(s) }{3 + e^{x(s)} + \cos x(s)} $.

But I suspect on this argument of this solution. This is my explanation

If I take some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ (such $t_0$ can exist) that $\eta = - \int_{0}^{t_0} \frac{\beta \sin x(s) }{3 + e^{x(s)} + \cos x(s)} ds \neq 0$, then $x(t_0) \equiv 0$.

There exists $t_1, t_2$ called $t_1 < t_0 < t_2$, since by uniqueness $x(t) \equiv 0$ thus $x(t_1)x(t_2) \leq 0$ i.e $x(t)$ changes the sign which is contradiction to what the problem statement is asking.

I appreciate, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: great question, +1, hope you receive good attention